# Android Login Screen with php mysql

Tags: php, android

I have successfully created Login page ... I have checked the username&password with my database successfully.Then I have set the condition `if(result!=null)` means start second activity.
What am I getting now na ,,even if username or password not correct also ,,it starts second page.What i have to do to make correct login screen...
Suggesstion plz ,Thanks in advance

AsynTask onpostexecute function

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //View your result here.
           if(result!= null) 
           {
               val=result;
               Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,Child_Profile.class);
               intent.putExtra("child_name", result);
               startActivity(intent);

           }

    }
```

My login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:background="#1E8EB6" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"

    android:background="#1E8EB6"
    android:layout_weight="1.5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_img"
        android:src="@drawable/camera" />

  </RelativeLayout>




<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#00677F"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/stat_notify_more"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/username">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:hint="@string/password"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="@string/login" 
        android:background="#054579"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/login"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/login"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:text="@string/remember" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="@string/forget"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

  </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"


    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#054579"
        android:text="@string/signup"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

  </RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

My Login.java, Final working code

```
   package com.example.certify.schoolapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {
    private TextView head;
    private EditText username,password;
    private Button login,signup,forget;
    private static String user,pass,val,result="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    head=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup=(Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    forget=(Button) findViewById(R.id.forget);
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new sendPostData().execute();

        }
    });
}

private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {  

 try{

             user = username.getText().toString(); 
             pass = password.getText().toString();
             String link="http://192.168.1.5:81/arun/loginpost.php?";
                String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") 
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user, "UTF-8");
                data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") 
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                URL url = new URL(link);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter
                (conn.getOutputStream()); 
                wr.write( data ); 
                wr.flush(); 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                   sb.append(line);
                   break;
                }
               return sb.toString();
             }catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
             }
    }
       @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //View your result here.
           if(result.equals("wrong"))
           {
               Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Login.this,"incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
               toast.show(); 
           }
           else
           {
               Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,Child_Profile.class);
               intent.putExtra("child_name", result);
               startActivity(intent);
           }




        }
 }
}
```

My loginpost.php

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");

$db_select = mysql_select_db('my_db', $con);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Role FROM table1 where Username='$username' and Password='$password'",$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row[0];
if($data){
echo $data;
}
else 
{
    echo "wrong";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you pass out of `doInBackground` as the string value is the `Result` in `onPostExecute`.

Looking at your `doInBackground` there does not seem to be a path where the returned string can ever not be `null`.

Also, it is bad to check for it being set or not set as an indication of the user authenticating successfully. I would instead pass back a boolean or still better a user object you have made with the users details in.

I would change :

```
 if(result!= null)
```

to

```
 if(result.eques("OK"))
```

Where `OK` is the expected response from the server on a successful login. 
[Not really recommend and I doubt your PHP script returns that.]

Comment: if (result.equals("user1"))
{
}
,,It works ,,,but am getting user1 dynamically,,,
How to do now

Comment: My mysql query for this ,,I think u will understand now

$result = mysql_query("SELECT Role FROM table1 where Username='$username' and Password='$password'",$con);

Comment: Is it that you want to populate the "user1 string dynamically? Or did you want to read the "Roles" as well in the result?

Comment: If the username and password correct means ,,,i will get Role value,,,
Then i want to check if condition,,,If true means start activity,,,else display toast
Or what else to do to make this happen

Comment: So technically speaking if you do your SQL and it returns no rows then you should get back an empty string from your server call. So you can change your logic to if (!results.equals("")). This would seem to work with then being passed to your new activity. However I would change the catch block to return ""; not the exception.

Comment: Glad to hear. Can you mark my response as an answer please. Would be very much appreciated. Happy coding.

Comment: Guys here I have updated my complete code ,,,find it useful,,,,
Once again thanks to you